# is it possible to use an external vectorizer in a standard SpaCy pipeline?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, huggingface-transformers

I have a script that relies almost entirely on SpaCy for a series of nlp tasks.
Since SpaCy only supports 3 english models by default (sm, md, lg), i would like to replace them with an external model such that i can vectorize my text and perform all the SpaCy methods i currently do in my pipeline.

Is it possible to replace the `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')`
line with something else without affecting the rest of my pipeline? For example by defining 'nlp' with one of the language models supported in the transformers library?

For example, i use SpaCy's `(a).similarity(b)` method, and would like to retain the pipeline which includes this, except have the calculations based on the word vectors generated by a non-default language model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how exactly you are intending to use it but it is possible to inherit from SpaCy classes overriding only `similarity` method that would use any other vector model that you might want.

So, depending on which `Doc`, `Span` or `Token` you want to have support your custom similarity you can do something along the lines of:

```
from spacy import Doc

class MyDoc(Doc):
    def __init__(...):
       super(Doc, self).__init__(...)

       self.__mymodel = <load your special vector model>

    def __similarity(v1, v2):
         <your implementation of similarity>

    def similarity(doc):
       v1 = <get vector for self from self.__mymodel>
       v2 = <get vector for doc param from self.__mymodel> 
       return self.__similarity(v1, v2)
```

You can use analogous approach for `Span` or `Token` classes.